# Can "$.extend({}, options)" use the "delegate" functionality in the JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, delegates

Can "$.extend({}, options)" use the "delegate" functionality in the JQuery? I have this question because I use below JQuery javascript to show a pop up menu in the jsp page.

```
/*
jQuery Pop Menu
Version: beta
Author: Guc. http://www.gucheen.pro
Based on jQuery 2.0.3
*/

(function ($) {

$.fn.popmenu = function (options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        'controller': true,
        'width': '300px',
        'background': '#34495e',
        'focusColor': '#1abc9c',
        'borderRadius': '10px',
        'top': '50',
        'left': '0',
        'iconSize': '100px',
        'color': '#fff',
        'border': '0px'
    }, options);
    if (settings.controller === true) {
        var temp_display = 'none';
    } else {
        var temp_display = 'block';
    }
    var tar = $(this);
    var tar_body = tar.children('ul');
    var tar_list = tar_body.children('li');
    var tar_a = tar_list.children('a');
    var tar_ctrl = tar.children('.pop_ctrl');

    function setIt() {
        tar_body.css({
            'display': temp_display,
            'position': 'absolute',
            'margin-top': -settings.top,
            'margin-left': -settings.left,
            'background': settings.background,
            'width': settings.width,
            'float': 'left',
            'padding': '0',
            'border-radius': settings.borderRadius,
            'border': settings.border
        });
        tar_list.css({
            'display': 'block',
            'color': settings.color,
            'float': 'left',
            'width': settings.iconSize,
            'height': settings.iconSize,
            'text-align': 'center',
            'border-radius': settings.borderRadius
        });
        tar_a.css({
            'text-decoration': 'none',
            'color': settings.color
        });
        tar_ctrl.hover(function () {
            tar_ctrl.css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }, function () {
            tar_ctrl.css('cursor', 'default')
        });
        tar_ctrl.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            tar_body.show('fast');
            $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
                var _con = tar_body;
                if (!_con.is(e.target) && _con.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    _con.hide();
                }
                //_con.hide(); some functions you want
            });
        });
        tar_list.hover(function () {
            $(this).css({
                'background': settings.focusColor,
                'cursor': 'pointer'
            });
        }, function () {
            $(this).css({
                'background': settings.backgrounds,
                'cursor': 'default'
            });
        });
    }
    return setIt();

};}(jQuery));
```

I use this popmenu.js after I connect with the HTML strings responded by the ajax json from the back-end Spring-MVC controller to display a pop up menu on the page. Since I re-connect with the HTML strings, so I have to use the delegate function to show the menu.
If I use below code without "delegating", all is good.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        /* $('#demo_box').popmenu(); */
        $('#ListOrLayout').popmenu(
                {
                'background':'#fff',
                'color':'#000',
                'focusColor':'#21a0df',
                'borderRadius':'0',
                'top': '0', 
                'left': '0',
                'border':'1px solid #211d1d'
                }
                );
       /*  $('#demo_box_3').popmenu({'width': '200px', 
       'background':'#223','focusColor':'#ee5','borderRadius':'10px', 'top': 
       '70', 'left': '-40', 'color':'#1265fe','border':'3px solid #0035fe'}); 
       */
       })
       </script>
```

And also the HTML I am using:

```
<div id="content">
<table  border = "1">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="maincheck" name="maincheck"/></td>
<td>目录/文件</td>
<td>名称</td>
<td>大小</td>
<td>最后修改时间</td>
<td>
<div id="ListOrLayout"><span class="fa fa-list-ul"></span> 
<span class="pop_ctrl"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        <ul>
            <li><div>查看格式</div></li>
            <li><span>列表 
  </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><i 
  class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></span></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:getFileLayout();"><span>网格 
  </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><i 
  class="fa fa-th"></i></span></a></li>

        </ul>
  </div> 
  ...
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.popmenu.js"> 
</script>
```

What i am now writing the JS is below:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.min.js">
jQuery("#content").on("#ListOrLayout", popmenu(

{'background':'#fff',
'color':'#000',
'focusColor':'#21a0df',
'borderRadius':'0',
'top': '0', 
'left': '0',
'border':'1px solid #211d1d'}
));
</script>
```

But this is nonfunctional. I don't know the exact event of the popmenu.js to delegate to the ancestor. So any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Comment: This problem was solved by myself. Since it is mainly due to not being known by the jquery.min.js and jquery.popmenu.js when ajax insert the new html into the #content by the statement "$("#content").html(theHtml);" , so I just call a function which is below the </body> to reload the jquery js and the popmenu js.

Comment: ...
$("#content").html("");
$("#content").html(theHtml);
needReloadInAsyncLoad();
...

Comment: the needReloadInAsyncLoad() function should be located below the </body> element. And its code is below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<script>
function needReloadInAsyncLoad()
{
    //ajax异步回发需要重新执行的js函数
    //alert("async");
 new_element=document.createElement("script");
 new_element.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
 new_element.setAttribute("src","${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.min.js");// 在这里引入了jquery.min.js
 document.body.appendChild(new_element);
 new_element=document.createElement("script");
 new_element.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
 new_element.setAttribute("src","${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.popmenu.js");// 在这里引入了jquery.popmenu.js
 document.body.appendChild(new_element);
  $('#ListOrLayout').popmenu(
       {
       'background':'#fff',
       'color':'#000',
       'focusColor':'#21a0df',
       'borderRadius':'0',
       'top': '0', 
       'left': '0',
       'border':'1px solid #211d1d'
       }
       );
}
</script>
```